# laravel image url not redirecting to home page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi everybody in my laravel project the url of any image like 
http://kemakon-app.com/storage/images/Screenshot_10.png is redirected to homepage  storage link but still getting the error any idea why

```
     'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
                    'visibility'=> 'public',

    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Can you share your code? You might also want to read this if you haven't already. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: @TobiasBarsnes i edited My Code take a lock

Comment: I take it you have already ran the "php artisan storage:link" command?